# Why does margin attribute not work in the recyclerview row layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two xml layouts for a recyclerview viewholder. I am using a LinearLayoutManager.

xml1:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="5dp">

     <...ChildViews...>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

xml2

```
<FrameLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="5dp">

       <...ChildViews...>

   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

If I inflate xml1, then there is no margin. But on inflation of xml2 then the margin is rendered. What is the reason?

Comment: How do you verify if the margin is rendered? What are the child views?

Comment: Make sure CardView is your parent layout. Also how did u check that margin is rendered or not?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I verified margin is not rendered by adding background color to the view.